# How can I detect a user recording my iOS app with the ReplayKit screen recording APIs?

Tags: ios, video-recording

Apple posts a reliable notification for screenshot detection which I've been using, but I'd like to also detect if the user is recording my app with the new ReplayKit API. We can try to get a UIScreenDidConnectNotification or test the .mirroredScreen property to see if there's anything going on, but neither of these are reliable, despite Apple's old technote (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1738/_index.html) saying otherwise. We could look at the height of the status bar, but that has false positives.
Has anyone gotten something working for this?

Comment: Have you tried `[[RPScreenRecorder sharedRecorder] isRecording]`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried registering a RPScreenRecorderDelegate. There is a screenRecorderDidChangeAvailability callback.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorderdelegate?language=objc

Comment: Yes but this won't work because we want to check the status immediately on startup